# Shell generate command arguments based on a list of strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I recently came across the following docker command which is so lengthy,

```bash
docker run -it -v $PWD/config:/opt/ibm/datapower/drouter/config -v $PWD/local:/opt/ibm/datapower/drouter/local -v $PWD/certs:/opt/ibm/datapower/root/secure/certs -e DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true -e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true -p 9090:9090 -p 9022:22 -p 5554:5554 -p 8000-8010:8000-8010 --name idg ibmcom/datapower
```

Is there a way to shorten it by reducing the repetition?

For example, there are multiple `-v` arguments which could expressed as for following,

```
for each string in ['config', 'local', 'certs']:
    -v $PWD/$$string:/opt/ibm/datapower/drouter/$$string
```

Is there any compact way to do this in bash or zsh (in a way similar to shell expansion, without writing another line)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this:

```bash
docker run -it $(for d in config local certs; do echo -n "-v $PWD/$d:/opt/ibm/datapower/drouter/$d "; done) -e DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true -e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true -p 9090:9090 -p 9022:22 -p 5554:5554 -p 8000-8010:8000-8010 --name idg ibmcom/datapower
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in `zsh`:

```
docker run -it \
  $(printf -- "-v $PWD/%1\$s:/opt/ibm/datapower/drouter/%1\$s " config local certs)\
  -e DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true -e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true \
  -p 9090:9090 -p 9022:22 -p 5554:5554  -p 8000-8010:8000-8010 \
  --name idg ibmcom/datapower
```

This uses POSIX `%$1s` argument indexing in `printf` to include the same parameter multiple times in the output (config, local, certs in your example).  Apparently `bash` does not support this (yet).

The line continuations (`\`) are just to make it a bit more readable; it can still be copied and pasted in a single action.